# Oak floor boards - getting an even finish with Polyx Oil

Tags: floor, wood-finishing, wood-filler

I’m using Polyx Oil hard wax finish on a new oak floor. The boards are grade A2 or B French oak, and I’ve used 2 part filler (Ronseal, “natural” colour) to fill splits, knots and some areas of uneven grain. I’m not happy with the way the filled areas are showing up - the Polyx accentuates the ultra-smooth filled areas, especially when the light reflects off the surface - see photos.

The boards looked acceptable after rubbing down, before I applied the Polyx. I don’t mind the fact that the filler is lighter than most of the boards, but does anyone have suggestions how I can get the texture to blend in better with the surrounding un-filled areas of wood?

Photos: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipN1iU0o4HXbhZHWH8LO2vZpjrh-UpiWJR93DbMgV2gy9iBGjWhytfYbEuWdD6rU4A?key=Um1sWmdFSl9NeHRsUGdBdjBJcl9NZF9hc1ZjUW13